yocto host: mariadb Docker container init fails with network mode host
I have a weird issue on a yocto based OS when starting up a mariadb container.
I am forced to use for the Docker container the network mode "host". We used the corresponding docker-compose file for quite a while successfully on different systems (Yocto based and Ubuntus). Now we created a new BSP and the container fails to initialize the root user.
We can easily reproduce the error using this command:
docker run --rm --network host --name some-mariadb --env MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw  mariadb:11.4.3-noble
The container stops with this error:
2024-08-14 08:30:03+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
2024-08-14 08:30:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Securing system users (equivalent to running mysql_secure_installation)
--------------
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost'= PASSWORD('my-secret-pw')
--------------

ERROR 1133 (28000) at line 10: Can't find any matching row in the user table

Versions:

Docker version 25.0.3
Yocto: scarthgap

What I tried after boiling down the issue to the error above:

Interestingly, this very command works on other Yocto based machines and Ubuntu 22.04
Docker volume issues could be excluded already since the issue can be reproduced without them
Tried mariadb version 11.4.3 and 10.6

Has anybody observed this behavior or has an idea what kernel options or docker settings might influence the container?

Host networking generally completely disables Docker's networking layer, and it's rarely necessary.  If you think host networking is implicated in this problem, does deleting the --net host option help?  (Consider docker network create a network for your application, and using that as a --net option instead.)

5min after posting, we found the answer to the riddle:
Do NOT use the host name "localhost" for your host when using Docker, this did greatly confuse mariadb. This was an oversight of me.
After changing the hostname using hostnamectl set-hostname my-host all was working.
Hope this helps somebody in the same situation

Thanks for sharing. I'll try to make this into a FAQ and maybe add some container prevention mechanisms or warnings.
